# Quartz.net Schedular working on local host but not working on shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net

I am using [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net) for scheduling tasks in my web site project. The jobs are getting executed when i run it locally from visual studio , but when i upload the website on shared hosting it doesn't work.

Can any one tell me what could be the reason behind this ?

```
public class JobSchedular
{
   Private Static IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
    public static void Start()
    {

        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail SendWeeklyMailJob = JobBuilder.Create<SendWeeklyMailJob>().Build();
        IJobDetail SendQuarterMailJob = JobBuilder.Create<SendQuarterlyMailJob>().Build();

        //ITrigger SendWeeklyMailJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        //    .WithIdentity("SendWeeklyMailJob", "SendWeeklyMailJobTrigger")
        //    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
        //    .WeeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(DayOfWeek.Monday, 5, 15))
        //    .Build();

        ITrigger SendQuarterMailJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("SendQuarterMailJob", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInHours(24))
            .Build();

        ITrigger SendWeeklyMailJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("SendWeeklyMailJob", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInMinutes(1))
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(SendWeeklyMailJob, SendWeeklyMailJobTrigger);
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(SendQuarterMailJob, SendQuarterMailJobTrigger);

    }
}
```

This is my job class.

And this is how i start that job in global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    JobSchedular.Start(); 
}
```

Can i get the reason why it is not working on server after deployment ? how to make it run on server ?

Comment: Application_Start is only called during the first request after the recycle or startup.

Comment: @Seany84 that i am aware of. but then how to make this work on shared hosting where IIS recycles applications. How to create a singleton object that stays in memory and does the job.

Comment: @SachinTrivedi, were you able to solve this issue? Cause I am facing the same issue

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder No i wasnt. I used the timer class instead.

Comment: JFYI, I have solved it please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820464/quartz-net-scheduler-is-working-on-local-while-debugging-but-not-on-production

Answer (score 1):

You're losing the reference to the scheduler. The scheduler should be a long-lived object in your application, a singleton is ideal.

However, there are issues with running Quartz.net embedded in an application because IIS recycles applications and thus will kill your scheduler.

Comment: That means it is server issue ? Is there any way i can programmatically keep my scheduler object alive ? Because this works fine on my local host.

Comment: Your server may behave differently than the server running locally. Make your scheduler reference static, and that will keep it around. For example, in the code you posted, pulling the declaration of scheduler out of the Start method and making it a private static variable should do the trick. It's not the ideal way to do it but it will give you an example.

Comment: See my updated code as per your suggestion. Still it is not working.